# Why don't we need to import something when use Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm new to React, still struggling to understand some basics, sorry if my question seems to be weird.  We know we need to import modules as

```
import sth from 'sth';
```

so when we use Jest, don't we need to do as:

```
import { test, expect...} from 'Jest';
```

Comment: The Jest testing methods are likely defined as [global variables](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/) somewhere internally before running your test code - seems to be a common trend with testing packages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @nahanil points out, Jest puts the methods you need in the global scope of your NodeJS runtime. If you put a `console.log(global)` in your file when running jest, you will see the methods are hooked onto the global scope. Other libraries such as [`assert`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) does not follow the same convention, and you will need to import the assertions you need.

That happens here: 
https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/160d27ae9b6728dccf268f8a98351bcf82a7d9e1/packages/jest-environment-node/src/index.ts#L21

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the first section in [official documentation api](https://jestjs.io/docs/api)
 :

> In your test files, Jest puts each of these methods and objects into the global environment. You don't have to require or import anything to use them. However, if you prefer explicit imports, you can do import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'.

```js
import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'
```